# Is the symmetry of u function for  the robust M estimation mandatory?

Tags: regression, robust, irls

I have build a $\rho$ function which has the following definition:

\begin{equation}
\rho(x)=
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  4- \frac{8}{x^2} \text{if } x \lt-2\\ 
  \frac{x^2}{2} \text{if } x \in [-2,3]  \\
                 9-\frac{81}{2*x^2} \text{if } x \gt 3
 \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}

The function has the continuity and derivability properties, but is asymetric.
Can be solved using Iteratively reweighted least squares (IRLS) method?

The $u$ function is:

$
u(x)=\begin{equation}
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \frac{16}{x^4} \text{ if } x \lt-2\\ 
    1 \text{ if } x \in [-2,3]  \\
                 \frac{81}{x^4} \text{ if } x \gt 3
 \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
$

For the IRLS method, the symmetry  of $u$ function is mandatory?

Comment: No [question mark in the title]: only the re-descending behavior matters from a bdp point of view. Yes [first question mark in the text], from an IRLS point of view this loss function is not more difficult than, say, Huber's. No [second question mark], there are other asymmetric $M$ functions and these could be solved by IRLS (although in practice they are not). But i'd be remiss if i didn't ask: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need my estimator instead of Huber M estimator. The solution is to use $u$ function in IRLS method. I don't know what is the effect of symmetry property.